# Adding an extra dimension with size None to a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dimensions

How do you add a `None` outer dimension to a tensor ?

Specifically, I have a  tensor of shape [299,299] that I want to return as output from a tensorflow `SavedModel` object. But the `SavedModel` object wants an unknown outer dimension to be able to deal with batches.

`tf.expand_dims()` adds an extra dimension but it is set to 1.

Answer (score -2):

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf    
        x = tf.constant([3., 2.])
```

You can use [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) for this,

```
In [1]: tf.reshape(x, [2, 1])
Out[1]: TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1)])
```